# Using two nested loops, display in the window the following line: 11 12 13 21 22 23 31 32 33 JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have a problem with a nested for loop and not be able to resolve the task.
Could you please help me find a solution?

Please see the code below. It is what i was able to do.

```
<script>
let str='';
for ( let i =11; i<=33; i+=10){
  str=''
  for (let j =1; j<=3; j++){
    document.write(i+' ')
  }
}
</script>
```

My result is wrong : 11 11 11 21 21 21 31 31 31

Comment: `document.write((i+j) + ' ')` and j should go from 0 to 2.

Comment: Just make both loops go from 1 to 3, and display  `i * 10 + j`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your sequence: Each number is the sum of `i` and `j`, and `j` should iterate from `0` to `2`;

suppose `i = 11`

```
i + 0 = 11
i + 1 = 12
i + 2 = 13
```

*Where j is 0,1,2*

Working solution:

```js
let str='';
for ( let i =11; i<=33; i+=10){
  str=''
  for (let j =0; j<=2; j++){
    const num = i + j;
    document.write(num + ' ')
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can try this for i and j both between 1-3.

```js
let str = '';
for (let i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
  for (let j = 1; j <= 3; j++) {
    document.write(i.toString() + j.toString() + ' ')
  }
}
```